# installing glassfish on ubuntu karmic using synaptics package manager

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, glassfish

I'm trying to learn to use glassfish for the first time. My IDE is netbeans and I've installed the glassfish plugin for netbeans. I opened up synaptics package manager and typed in glassfish. My choices were

imqv2

glassfish-activaton

glassfish-mail

glassfish-appserv

glassfish-toplink-essentials

glassfish-jmac-api

glassfish-javaee

I'm not sure what is in each package, or which package are needed. I can't seem to find anything that tells me anything descriptive about these packages.

I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to install glassfish, but I'd prefer to use apt-get / synaptics to install glassfish so that syntactics can take care of updating.

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer your question, I think that a typical install would at least include glassfish-appserv, glassfish-javaee, glassfish-toplink-essentials (for JPA).

But for development, I'd warmly recommend to use **GlassFish v3** (because of the session preservation across deployments feature, to maximize productivity) and to install it **manually** in your home directory. Download the self-extracting installer file from [here](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/v3-final.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run the latest and greatest software?  It looks like [Synaptic has Glassfish version 2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=glassfish) which is an entire major version out of date.

Just for the record: I love Ubuntu and their (well, Debian's) package management system.  However, for any Java applications, I prefer to do manual installations.  So, my Maven, Eclipse, Tomcat, Glassfish, etc. were all done through manual installs for the newest version... and because `sudo apt-get install` winds up throwing the app in some weird place and can have unexpected behavior.

Here is how you can do a manual install...

1. Download Glassfish: `wget http://download.java.net/glassfish/v3/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip`
2. Extract the archive anywhere on your filesystem
3. Inside your IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse, setup a new server and point it at where you extracted the file
4. It's also useful to add a new environment variable to ~/.bashrc file, which will make it easier to start the server from the command-line, e.g. `$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1`

Another cool thing to try, if you're into maven, is to use the [maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin](http://blogs.oracle.com/sirajg/entry/using_maven_plugin_for_v3).  It's a clean way to get a web app up and running and not need to manually install glassfish and not even have to use an IDE.

You might also try asking this question at [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com) if you really want to get it working with Synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this here is still open...
but if you know how to handle shell commands on ubuntu then you might find this here helpful:
http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-311-on-ubuntu